# @ethereumjs/tx Error: Returned error: Insufficient funds. The account you tried to send transaction from does not have enough funds

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, ethereumjs-tx, sendsignedtransaction

Moving to `@ethereumjs/tx` npm package after `ethereumjs-tx` has been marked as deprecated.
My `from` address has sufficient `Kovan` network balance, but the following code throwing `Insufficient funds` error.

Unable to figure out solution from [github issue](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo/issues/1228)

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
import { Transaction } from '@ethereumjs/tx';
import Common, { Hardfork, Chain } from '@ethereumjs/common';

// Provider
var provider = 'https://kovan.infura.io/v3/xxxxxxxx';
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(provider))
const from = '0xf169ae25afdb8cea6dc2de8938738234bafcaeb8'
const pKey = Buffer.from('e7abf3413731cea1963b845baede4925d7f7310dcc427513fa5752ec11fd098d', 'hex')
const to = '0x3314bf4B1286F495B1fe8908F7d0f05D8818b168'
const valueInEther = 0.001

web3.eth.getTransactionCount(from, "pending").then((txnCount) => {
    console.log('From address nonce:' + web3.utils.numberToHex(txnCount));
    web3.eth.getBalance(from).then((balRes) => {
        console.log('From address balance (eth):' + web3.utils.fromWei(balRes.toString(18)));
    });
    var txObject = {
        nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txnCount),
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(1000),
        gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(21000),
        to: to,
        value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei(valueInEther.toString(), 'ether')),
        chainId: web3.utils.toHex(42) // kovan
    }
    const common = new Common({ chain: Chain.Kovan, hardfork: Hardfork.Istanbul }); //, hardfork: 'petersburg'
    let tx = new Transaction(txObject, { common });
    const signedTx = tx.sign(pKey);
    const serializedTx = signedTx.serialize();
    var rawTxHex = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex');
    console.log("Signed transaction hex: " + rawTxHex);
    // boardcast signed tx
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(rawTxHex)
        .on('transactionHash', (txHash) => { console.log('transaction hash: ', txHash); })
        .on('receipt', receipt => { console.log('Receipt: ', receipt); })
        .catch(error => { console.log('Error: ', error.message); });

    console.log(" ******************** Send result: ******************** ");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake, actually I am using Ethereum HD wallets and by mistake I copied private key of index 0 address and using it with address having index 1.